# How to Order By field List names in Jpa repository

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

I need to order my selected items by `status` name sequence. (active <- inactive).

I wrote its SQL query correctly as follows. I need to convert it into jpa repository. please help me.

```
select * from device
 where status in ('active', 'inactive')
order 
    by field(status,'active', 'inactive')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use a case when expression i.e. `case status when 'active' then 0 when 'inactive' then 1 else null end`. With JPA Criteria this looks roughly like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder.SimpleCase<String> caseExprssion = cb.selectCase(root.get("status"));
caseExprssion.when(cb.literal("active"), cb.literal(0));
caseExprssion.when(cb.literal("inactive"), cb.literal(1));
caseExprssion.otherwise(cb.nullLiteral(Integer.class));
criteriaQuery.orderBy(caseExpression);
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution, Kudos mate